# Regex overlapping

Tags: regex

I want to capture all occurrences of a letter, followed by a digit, but no letter before the above letter.
So, there is a `f9` match in `f9`, `3f9`, `f99`, but not in `af9`.
I have the following regex: `([^a-z]|^)([a-z])(\d)`.

Why doesn't it match both `f9` and `x0` in `f9x0` and how to achieve this? It matches only `f9`.
In `f9 x0` there are two matches.

Thank you.

Comment: Enter your regular expression into a website such as regex101.com and see what your regex means.

Comment: There is no character before the`x` but you require one. You are looking for a neg. lookbehind.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Learning Regular Expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736/learning-regular-expressions)

Comment: `all occurrences of a symbol` ... `f` is not a symbol, it's a word character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you asked it:
*"capture all occurrences of a symbol, followed by a digit, **but no symbol before** the above symbol"*

```
/(?<=\d|^)\w\d/g
```

Match:

```
f9      >> f9
f9x0    >> f9, x0
af9    
3f9     >> f9
```

[Regex101.com demo](https://regex101.com/r/CeuYkk/1)

Comment: @AndrewFount first of your regex has too many matching groups making the result quite odd: https://regex101.com/r/h07ed8/1 - Secondly the option `^`(*start of string*)  in ([^a-z]|^) already **matched and consumed** the first match `f9` - and will not proceed further to `x0`.

Comment: First capture is `f9` (with the start of the string). The second match should be `9x0`. It doesn't work because `9` is already captured, correct?

Comment: @AndrewFount  Yes. If by contrast you use a non-consuming Positive Lookbehind `(?<=` the thing will work as intended for the next group `x0` as well.

Answer (score 1):

There is no character before the `x` but you require one. You are looking for a lookbehind:

```
(?:^|(?<![a-z]))[a-z]\d
```

See a [**demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/kNkLrg/1/).

Comment: There is `9` before `x` and it is not a letter, as required.

Comment: Reading the question, I think this should be ok right? If I am not mistaken, you can shorten it to `(?<![a-z])[a-z]\d`